# I can't print in the draft mode with my HP Deskjet 1660

Tags: printing, hp, hplip

My printer is a Deskjet 1660 and with Ubuntu 12.10 I began to use it. The only problem is when I tried to use the draft mode in order to save ink, the job cancels automatically. I don't know why. I need help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[When will hplip support ubuntu 12.10?](https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/211854)

Here is one of the answers:

> Hi,
> Ubuntu 12.10 will be supported in our next release of HPLIP which migh happen in couple of weeks time or so.
>
> As a temporary workaround, please
>
> 1. Download HPLIP-3.12.10a (e.g to `~/Downloads`)
> 2. Open Terminal and go to `~/Downloads/hplip-3.12.10a`
> 3. Open `~/Downloads/hplip-3.12.10a/installer/distros.dat` and then replace "12.04" with "12.10"
> 4. `./install.py` (this will start the auto installer)
>
> => Reconfigure print queue with the commands in the terminal mentioned below.
> => `system-config-printer` (remove all print queues)
> => `su -c "hp-plugin"` (This will download right plugin)
> => `hp-setup` (It should not be run in a root mode. This command is adding print queue, make sure you select ppd name having "-ps" or "hpcups" substring)
> => Try printing now.

[Sanjay Kumar (sanjay-kumar14)](https://launchpad.net/%7Esanjay-kumar14)

Comment: I followed the instructions of the installation site, I wrote in the terminal sh hplip-3.12.10a.run but the terminal says this can't be open, can you help me?

Comment: every 12.04 I see in this file I will replace to 12.10?

Comment: Most Likely Try it, but back up the file just in case.